# MinGW command line limitation?

Tags: windows, shell, mingw

I just installed MinGW in order to use `grep` to do a customized search in my source files. However, I can't seem to be able to `cd` out of the `MSYS` directory, which is directory in the base installation directory of MinGW.

Am I doing something wrong, or is the desired functionality not offered by MinGW? I would think a simple grep search should be a core function of a "minimalist GNU for Windows" software.

(I know Cygwin exists but I thought I would be able to get by using this smaller MinGW program.)

Comment: This isn't a programming Q, but as MingW is primarily used to build projects (programs), I'll comment that `cd` and `grep` both work for me. And sorry, but this is just you saying "it doesn't work". We need reproducible evidence ;-) Please update your Q with a sample of your problem (2 dirs, 2 small files) and a grep target, then show your navigation and use of commands (output) (and error messages?), maybe we can help. And for starters, how are you running MingW to have a terminal windows displayed? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I started MinGW by double clicking on C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat. Then, upon issuing: `$ ls /`, I get 
`bin  etc  home  m.ico  msys.bat  msys.ico  postinstall  sbin  share`, which is clearly just the installation directory of MSYS.

Comment: What happens when you type cd ~ then what is the output of pwd?

Comment: and did you try `cd bin`, and `cd /c/path/to/whatever`?  Are you still stuck? Can you update your Q per my comments above? To find the best "laucher" for **mingw**, I use the Start Bar-> Programs->Search and type mingw. There are several items that turn up, but look for the obvious one. Good luck.

Comment: $cd /c$ worked for me, thanks. $cd ~$ simply went to $C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe

```
cd ~
```

to cd to your home directory should work (it works for me).
Or simply:

```
cd c:\whatever
```

Alos, you can checkout [the official mingw starter guide](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/mingw_for_first_time_users_howto)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks TimTheEnchanter. Could you take a look at my comment under the question?